# What first should be done: update kernel or update environment?

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, upgrade

I have Linux Mint 18.0 and 4.4 kernel.

In update manager I see that I can update system to 18.3  and  there is also 4.13 kernel available.

What should I do first: update environment or update kernel?

1. Update environment to 18.0 then kernel to 4.13
2. Update kernel to 4.13 then environment to 18.0

Comment: I believe `sudo apt dist-upgrade` should do both!

Comment: Why not both? Or better yet, do that in a test machine/clone first. It is a good opsec pratice <darth vader voice> I find your need to validate every single action with others disturbing. <off> On a serious note, *if I had to chose* I would update first the environment. Nevertheless, for an informed action, only reading the release notes of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System versions 18.0 and 18.3 both support both versions of the kernel. This is specifically to allow you to choose which kernel you want in whichever order you want.

Which one you should install first is up to you. If you have features of Linux 4.13 you want now install the kernel now. If you're ready to upgrade to the new system version then do that. If you want both do both.

It's typical that a version of a distribution will support multiple Linux versions simultaneously.